# objective-c - NSTimer falling more and more behind

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I have a NSTimer (running on main thread) that is supposed to go off every 0.02s. However, I notice that as memory usage start going up (the app captures a frame every tick and stores in an array) subsequent ticks begin to take more then 0.02s.

How can I solve this issue? I'm starting to think NSTimer is not suited for high-frequency tasks like this.

Comment: Maybe the activity you're triggering takes more than 0.02s to complete.

Comment: @HotLicks maybe, but I thought the next tick should not wait for previous tick to finish.

Comment: But the next tick must wait for an available processor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html) state,

> A timer is not a real-time mechanism; it fires only when one of the
>   run loop modes to which the timer has been added is running and able
>   to check if the timer’s firing time has passed. Because of the various
>   input sources a typical run loop manages, the effective resolution of
>   the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of 50-100
>   milliseconds.

Since 100 milliseconds = .1 seconds and your timer is supposed to run every  0.02 seconds, your timer schedule is far shorter than the timer's effective resolution and so you timer can easily get out of sync.

Comment: Thanks Lyndsey. Do you know of any alternatives to high frequency tasks like this?

Comment: @AndyHin I'd recommend looking into CADisplayLink: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/index.html